# Await has no effect on the type of this type of expression in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, async-await

I searched about this but I didn't find anything specific for what I need. If there is one, please, share here.

I am creating the video upload Api using Vimeo . Problem is, the editor returns the message "'await' has no effect on the type of this expression". And the app indeed crashes since there is no data yet.

```
 const videoUpload = async (data) => {
        let file_name = data.path;
        await client.upload(
            file_name,
            {
                name: "Untitled",
                description: "The description goes here.",
            },
            (uri) => {
                client.request(uri + "?fields=link", function (error, body, statusCode, headers) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log("There was an error making the request.");
                        console.log("Server reported: " + error);
                    }
                    data.link = body.link;
                });
            },
            (bytes_uploaded, bytes_total) => {
                var percentage = ((bytes_uploaded / bytes_total) * 100).toFixed(2);
                console.log(bytes_uploaded, bytes_total, percentage + "%");
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log("Failed because: " + error);
            }
        );
        return data;
    };
```

Comment: Maybe `client.upload` doesn't return a promise ? So it would be nothing to `await` for.

Comment: I just want to return data only after the execution of client.uplaoad  method

Comment: If client.upload is not asynchronous you dont need to await to do that, just remove await.

Comment: Maybe you can show the implementation of client.upload() ? If I understand well you want to wait for the request to respond, but client.upload doesn't return the promise directly ? Maybe you can wrap your call in a promise and pass the resolve function to the callback inside of client.upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `upload` method does not return a promise, but instead uses a callback pattern. This means `upload` returns before any of the callback arguments are *called*. Using `await` on that will not have the desired effect, as `upload` just returned `undefined`, and `await` will just wrap that as a promise and see it is already resolved. The same problem happens again with the call to `request`.

In such situations you can check whether the API provides a promise-based alternative, but I couldn't find it. So then you can *promisify* the relevant methods yourself. For instance, like this:

```
// create an promise-enabled alternative for client API
const promiseClient = {
    upload(fileName, options, progressCallback) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            client.upload(fileName, options, resolve, progressCallback, reject)
        );
    },
    request(uri) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
            client.request(uri, (error, body, statusCode, headers) =>
                error ? reject(error) : resolve({body, statusCode, headers})
            )
        );
    }
};

const videoUpload = async (data) => {
    const file_name = data.path;
    try {
        const uri = await promiseClient.upload(
            file_name, 
            {
                name: "Untitled",
                description: "The description goes here.",
            },
            (bytes_uploaded, bytes_total) => {
                const percentage = ((bytes_uploaded / bytes_total) * 100).toFixed(2);
                console.log(bytes_uploaded, bytes_total, percentage + "%");
            }
        );
        const {body} = await promiseClient.request(uri + "?fields=link");
        data.link = body.link;
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Video upload failed because: ", error);
        throw error; // Maybe you want to cascade the error to the caller...
    }
};
```